# Removing spark.autotune.trackingId change in every notebook PR with Azure Synapse

Tags: azure, apache-spark, jupyter-notebook, azure-synapse

I am working with a git integrated Azure Synapse workspace. Currently on every PR, we are seeing changes to the `spark.autotune.trackingId` config within each modified notebook.

I have tried googling about this, and have struggled to find much detail - [outside of some others who are dealing with the same problem](https://dustinvannoy.com/2022/04/06/azure-synapse-ci-cd/)

I would like to understand what this config is for in the first instance, and if possible are we able to stop it from changing?

To be clear, this is a software engineering issue concerning an Azure tool used for software development, and how to engineer it correctly to behave a certain way when under SDLC, using CI/CD. I am adding this clarification as this question has been closed by stackoverflow admins, in my opinion incorrectly and without any reason given other than being 'off topic'. Which clearly is not the case. In any case this question is still unresolved and my software engineering team are still dealing with this issue. Many Thanks.